# Change appearance from terminal

Tags: terminal, system-settings, defaults

I know I  can change the appearance of my mac using the system preferences app, but is there a way to do this from the terminal?

I'm looking for something like `defaults write com.apple.systempreferences.general.appearance 'dark'`, but can't seem to find the right config value.

Edit: For clarity I want to change System Preferences > General > Appearance
[https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208976#:~:text=Turn%20on%20Dark%20Mode,the%20dark%20appearance%20at%20night](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208976#:%7E:text=Turn%20on%20Dark%20Mode,the%20dark%20appearance%20at%20night).

[image]

Comment: You will need to say the exact bit of appearance you want to chnage

Comment: That .plist does not exist, at least on the latest version of Big Sur on my MBP. `defaults read com.apple.systempreferences.general.appearance`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I tried to grep through potential general system preferences using the following command, but nothing showed up.

`ls -d ~/Library/Preferences/* | grep "com.apple" | grep -e "general" -e "prefer" -e "system" | xargs cat | grep "appearance"`

Comment: @Olshansk no I didn't, sorry. Was hoping someone here would know but no luck so far.